# Magento remove coupon code from users cart

Tags: php, jquery, magento

I am trying to build a JQuery .post() call that will remove a users coupon from the getQuote model ...  My problem is it doesn't error out, and it doesn't remove the code either.  Here is what I am doing:

```
<?php

$mageFilename =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app/Mage.php';

require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(false);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');

$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$quote = $session->getQuote();
$error = "fail";


if (isset($_POST['rem_coup'])) { 

    Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session")->setData("coupon_code","");

    //Apply the coupon to quote incase there is already a product in the cart or a quote is already generated
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->setCouponCode("")->collectTotals()->save();

   $error = "success";
}

echo $error;

?>
```

Of course it returns "success", but the code isn't removed.

This is the "removeFromCart.php" file in it's entirety.  All I need is a simple "remove coupon code from cart" script that I can use remotely from a jQuery .post() call.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why `Mage::app('admin');` if you update cart from frontend? Btw, you should better creae new extension with controller and implement needed logic there rather than creating some php files and include `Mage.php` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured it out ...

```
<?php
$mageFilename =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app/Mage.php';

require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
umask(0);
Mage::app('*******_english');


$error = "fail";

if (isset($_GET['rem_coup'])) { 
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
        Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->setData('coupon_code','')->save();  
        $error = "success";
}
?>
```

@ Slayer Birden  --  You were mostly right.  I needed the get core/session.  However, with my checkout/cart I needed `Mage::helper` not `Mage::getSingleton` as well.  This is a working version of the Ajax Call.

Comment: ``Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));`` this line just refers to the session, then you never use it? why? You don't need that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using separate script to work with Magento, you need to properly start session in order to be able to use Magento's session. Try to insert next code after `Mage::app()`:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'))->start();
```